# When professional mathematicians solve problems, do they use pen and paper or do they type directly into LaTeX?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question, article-writing

When professional mathematicians solve problems, do they type directly into LaTeX or do they solve problems using pen-and-paper? By professional mathematicians, I include those pursuing a mathematics PhD. I'm not a professional mathematician but have to use quite a bit of math for grad school, and have experimented with both approaches. Typing out is slower but I'm able to fit more formulas and other content onto a page.

Comment: This question is pretty subjective, so it's not really suited for this site, but I for one use lots of scratch paper or board space to solve problems, and only type them up when I'm reasonably sure it's worth keeping.  The correct answer is probably both.

Comment: I would say they definitely do not type directly into LaTeX. They use pen and paper or a white board. Sometimes to clarify their thoughts they might write up certain ideas in LaTeX, but that would be after the ideas were first worked out on paper.

Comment: You can't just type without writing by hand on a scratch paper otherwise you would not understand what you are typing.

Comment: Don't know how 'professional' I should claim to be, but I have a stack of used tablets with scratch-ings. TeX that looks good takes too much fussing to invest in something that's still in early draft stages. But sometimes scratch work is in R code.

Comment: LaTeX is for typesetting proofs, not creating them, you convert to LaTeX when you have finished your proof. It was *not* invented to be a formal language for proof writing, and I expect that Knuth would be aghast at people trying to use it that way, considering his stance on premature optimization. ;) IMHO, LaTeX is a lot easier to write than it is to read, although admittedly it does get easier with practice.